# Mysql Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a mysql query to fetch a number of id's(studentID), given below

```
select t1.studentID 
from remittedfees t1 
where (select t2.fees 
       from feesasigned t2 
       where t2.studentID=t1.studentID) = (select sum(t3.remittedAmt) 
                                           from remittedfees t3 
                                           where t3.studentID = t1.studentID);
```

but the query returns the following error

```
  ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

How can I rewrite the query to get the result ?

Comment: what are the fields you want to retrieve?

Comment: please add more information about your table structure with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [updated]:

```
SELECT t2.studentID 
  from feesasigned t2 
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t3.studentID, SUM(t3.remittedAmt) FeeSum
  FROM remittedfees t3 
  GROUP BY t3.studentID) v ON t2.studentID = v.studentID and t2.fees = v.FeeSum
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the `select t2.fees` query is doing just as the error says - returning more than one row. When doing an equality comparison like that, both sides of the `=` have to be single values. If one side returns 2+ values, then you end up with

```
1 = 1
2
3
```

ok... what's equal? 1=1? 2=1? 3=1? which single 'truth' value should be used as the result of the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to retrieve `StudentID` whose`fees` from `feesasigned` table is queal to the total `remittedAmt` from `remittedfees` table. Then try this:

```
SELECT  a.studentID, b.fees, SUM(a.remittedAmt) TotalFees
FROM    remittedfees a INNER JOIN feesasigned b
            on a.studentID = b.studentID
GROUP BY a.studentID, b.fees
HAVING b.fees = SUM(a.remittedAmt)
```

Comment: i think b.fees should be part of `group by` here or else it might throw an error

Comment: You can also remove extra join to remittedfees table and use `sum (a.remittedAmt)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
SELECT t2.studentID FROM feesasigned t2 
INNER JOIN 
    (select sum(t3.remittedAmt) as remitted_total, t3.studentID from remittedfees t3 
     GROUP BY t3.studentID) t4
ON
    t2.fees = t4.remitted_total AND t2.studentId = t4.studentID
```

Which returns the IDs of the student who has paid all their fees

Comment: when you do `sum(column), column2` you need to use `group by column2`, please update your query :)